# How to add the same label to multiple sliders in a Qualtrics survey using JavaScript (or another solution)?

Tags: javascript, slider, label, survey, qualtrics

For my Qualtrics survey, I have one question with 94 statements and a slider for the responses. Qualtrics only lets me add labels to the top of the first slider but I would like the same two labels on either side, showing "No more than usual (1)" and "Much more than usual (100)" repeated for every slider. This way participants can scroll down and keep seeing the labels on either side for each slider. I've seen that you can implement this using Javascript but I haven't been able to find the actual code anywhere. Any help would be much appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function () {
    let labs = document.querySelector(".labels-container"),
        sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-container");

    for (let i = 1; i < sliders.length; i++)
        sliders[i].insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", labs.outerHTML);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. I tried it out in Qualtrics and what now happens is that the question (rather than the slider labels) shows up both at the top and the very bottom of the slider section. Is it possible to repeat the slider headers on either side of each slider 94 times? :)

Comment: I am finding that this code when run and when in a preview or real survey in Chrome, when you inspect an element on the slider it crashes the browser.  You get an Aw, Snap! instance.  I have narrowed it down to this code.  Is anyone else having the same experience?  If in Qualtrics it works ok, try restarting the the survey and testing again as I find it does it on the second instance without fail.  I'm on chrome Version 120.0.6099.200 64 bit.

Comment: Ah! I've just noticed that this is using the addOnReady function.  I have used it in the addOnload function.  Would that be cause of the issue?  If so why?